# Is it possible to define a function outside of its class, just like C++ in Kotlin without inheriting the parent class

Tags: kotlin, generics

like in C++

```
returnType className::FunctionName(){
    //FUNCTION BODY
}
```

can we do same or alternative in Kotlin **without inheriting parent class**?.

Comment: If you mean a member function, then no, this is not possible. We can create class extensions, but this is not the same.

Comment: @broot What do mean by class extensions, like static functions or something

Comment: Yes, technically they're static functions, but with syntactic sugar to use them in a similar way to member functions: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html

Comment: They aren't always static functions. They can be defined inside other classes and use class members. If they are defined at the top level outside of any class, then they're static.

Answer (score 0):

You could create extension functions, only public functions will be allowed to be accessed via the extension functions however. For example, suppose you have some example class:

```
class Example() {
   fun exposed(string: String) = println(string);
   private fun notExposed(string: String) = println("private: ${string}")
}
```

and you want to be able to add some extension function, which will only have access to public member of the Example class:

```
//Outside of scope example class, inside root kt file or companion object
fun Example.test(){
    exposed("This is valid") //Works because it's a public member 
    notExposed("This doesn't compile") //Invalid because it's a private function.
}
```

Then you could access this extension via an instance of the example class:

```
fun main(){
    val example = Example()
    example.test()
}
```

This obviously won't compile due to the call to "notExposed" in the extension function, but the idea is that you can create static like functions outside of a given class allowing for some pretty interesting functionality.